# Wildflyで未処理例外のログ出力を制御したい

Tags: java, wildfly, jboss

Java8、Wildfly 10.1.0 を使っています。
JAX-RSで作ったWebAPI上で、未処理例外が発生した場合、自動的に`ERROR`レベルのログがスタックトレース含めて出力されますが、これを自分で制御する方法を探しています。

具体的には、特定の例外の場合だけ、ログを出力したくない（せめてINFO等の別レベルで出力したい）のです。

[この記事](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.1/html/development_guide/sect-exception_handling)により、未処理例外に対するHTTPレスポンスの独自制御はできました。
しかしこの`toResponse`メソッドに到達した時点で、すでに`ERRPR`のログが出力されています。
つまり、これより前のどこかに介入する必要がありそうなのですが、その方法が分かりません。

どなたかご存知でしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

フレームワークが出力している、

```
14:41:48,768 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-10) UT005023: Exception handling request to ...
```

のようなログは、[logging subsystem の設定](https://docs.wildfly.org/25/Admin_Guide.html#Logging) で制御することになると思います。

- [設定項目詳細](https://docs.wildfly.org/25/wildscribe/subsystem/logging/index.html)

`standalone.xml`(等)を開いて `urn:jboss:domain:logging` で検索すると該当箇所がヒットしますので、そこに設定を追加します。

```xml
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">
            ...
            <logger category="io.undertow.request">
                <level name="OFF"/>
            </logger>
            ...
        </subsystem>
```

上記の設定の場合、例外ログを含めた全ての `io.undertow.request` カテゴリのログが出力されなくなります。

ある特定の例外ログだけ出力を抑制する、というのは不可能だと思います。
(代替策としては、上記のように追加設定した `logger` にカスタム `handler` を設定することで、出力先を変えたり出力フォーマットを変えたりすることが考えられます。)